# Append Node returns NULL appending fist element

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having trouble appending nodes to my linked list when the link list is NULL. In main it always prints NIL. How do I fix this. Here is my implementation of linked list node, and the create node and append node functions.

```
struct LL_node {
    int data;
    struct LL_node* next;
  };
  typedef struct LL_node LL_node_t;

LL_node_t* create_node(int x){
  LL_node_t* node = (LL_node_t*)malloc(sizeof(LL_node_t)) ;
  node->data = x;
  node->next = NULL;
  return node;
}

void append_node(LL_node_t* start,int x){
  LL_node_t* node = create_node(x);
  if(start == NULL){
    start = node;
    return;
  }
  LL_node_t* nodes =  start;
  while(nodes->next != NULL){
    nodes =  nodes->next;
  }
  node->next = create_node(x);
}

int main(void) {
  LL_node_t* head = create_node(5);
  LL_node_t* nodes = NULL;
  append_node(nodes,3);
  printf("%p\n",nodes);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to print with `printf("%p\n",nodes);`?

Comment: `void append_node(LL_node_t* start,int x)` This passes the `start` pointer by value. `start = node;` This modifies the *copy* of the pointer received as an argument. It does not, and cannot, modify the value of the original pointer `nodes` in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

C is strictly call by value. When you pass `nodes` to `append_node`, inside the function you will have a copy of the pointer value. The modified value will not be passed back to the caller.

You have two options:

1. Return the modified value and assign it in the calling function
   (`main`) or
2. pass the address of the pointer to be able to modify
   the pointer in the called function (`append_node`).

First variant:

```
LL_node_t* append_node(LL_node_t* start,int x){
  LL_node_t* node = create_node(x);
  if(start == NULL){
    start = node;
    return start;
  }
  LL_node_t* nodes =  start;
  while(nodes->next != NULL){
    nodes =  nodes->next;
  }
  node->next = create_node(x);
  return start;
}

int main(void) {
  LL_node_t* head = create_node(5);
  LL_node_t* nodes = NULL;
  nodes = append_node(nodes,3);
  printf("%p\n",nodes);
  return 0;
}
```

Second variant:

```
void append_node(LL_node_t** start,int x){
  /* avoid dereferencing NULL pointer */
  if(start == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  LL_node_t* node = create_node(x);
  if(*start == NULL){
    *start = node;
    return;
  }
  LL_node_t* nodes =  *start;
  while(nodes->next != NULL){
    nodes =  nodes->next;
  }
  node->next = create_node(x);
}

int main(void) {
  LL_node_t* head = create_node(5);
  LL_node_t* nodes = NULL;
  append_node(&nodes,3);
  printf("%p\n",nodes);
  return 0;
}
```